# RDLC Report in asp.net C#

Tags: report, rdlc

Working on rdlc report in asp.net c#, in my report one large string is coming but its not show completely. if  show completely it will exceed to the right side of the report and not showing some of the columns..

I Need to fix the column size. If the String coming to it exceed the size then it can grow the column size downwards (Means Height can grow not width).

Comment: Can you add what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a reason for that , because usually if you have given a width the string will contain in the width and remaining will automatically come to the next line, but  it exists you can fix the column width and increase the height of the row and also try adding canGrow property in General as true follow following steps

1. Open property Widow from view of Visual studio
2. click on the required row
3. Go to property window
4. Change Can grow to true

Hope it is usefull